# Chrome Displays two Calendars in Date Field

Tags: chrome, date-picker

I have an unusual problem with one of my users using Chrome.

When he goes into a **Date field** in Salesforce using a **Chrome Browser**, he is presented with a calendar and previously entered dates.

- We cleared cookies. Nothing changed.
- We Used an **Incognito** Window; nothing changed.
- We used **FireFox** and it worked as expected; only showing the Salesforce Calendar Picker.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off autofill settings in chrome.

Goto [chrome://settings/?search=autofill](http://chrome://settings/?search=autofill) and turn off autofill settings for payment methods and addresses.